# Specifying default vhost on Apache2 with multiple vhost files

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have set up a Ubuntu Linux VPS with Moonshine (a Ruby on Rails deployment plugin/script) and hosting multiple sites on it (despite Moonshine being intended for one site/application), so far working well.

One little issue that I have with my server is that whenever I accidentally set up a vhost wrong or a vhost is not found, the browser is directed to the very first vhost site that I set up. Which concerns me because I don't want one site accidentally being associate with the other in case of some error or issue; what I would "rather" have it do is direct to some default place (like /var/www/default/oops.html) if there are any issues.

I've Googled the subject and the common answer is that order is everything in the vhost files, except I think that is assuming I have ALL my vhosts in one file. Instead, my vhosts are set up separately in the sites-available/enabled folders of apache (mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com, etc) and 'a2ensite' respectively, so how would I go about "ordering" these? (One of these files is a 'default' file, but doesn't seem to do anything.)

One other thing I saw was specify a default host in httpd.conf, except when I attempted to do so, it completely redirected ALL my vhost sites to the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu your vhosts will be loaded via `Include` statements within the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` configuration file. You're right that Apache treats the first VirtualHost it finds as the default if it can't match a request but just because the VirtualHost directives aren't in the same file doesn't stop you from ordering them.

Down the bottom of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` you can find the line:

`# Include the virtual host configurations:

Include sites-enabled/`

This is where Apache is picking up your VirtualHosts specified in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ so you've got two options:

Put an include to add a new VirtualHost above the above Include line in the `apache2.cnf` config file.

Or order the files in `sites-enabled`. I'm not sure on the exact mechanism Apache uses to read these files but I'm assuming it's alphabetical with numbers first (in the same way `ls` would list a directory). This is hinted at by the included default site on Ubuntu being called `000-default`. So based on that, to create a new default VirtualHost, you need to create a new VirtualHost config in `sites-available` called (for instance) `00_default_vhost.conf` and then enable it with `a2ensite`.

Comment: Completely didn't occur to me about the number ordering. I basically renamed default to 00-default and restarted Apache, now it goes exactly to the default where I specified. Thank you much.